# Does a Huntsman only exist for the span of a single dream?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, changeling-the-lost, changeling-the-lost-2e

In Changeling the Lost: Second Edition, it is said that a Huntsman's heart resides within a Bastion. It even specifies that

> the heart can found within
> the tempestuous mortal Bastion (p. 264)

So, the Bastion is one of a mortal dreamer.
It is also said that

> A Bastion only exists for the span of a single dream.
> When the dreamer wakes, whether naturally or because a
> paradigm shift jarred them awake, the Bastion crumbles
> and disappears (p. 222)

What happens when the Bastion containing the Huntsman's heart crumbles? Does it destroy the heart, which implies that a Huntsman only exist for the span of a single dream? That would seem to contradict the "Wild Hunt" paragraph.

> so long as their heart beats in their stolen
> Bastion, they reform somewhere in the Hedge within a
> month’s time to start again. And even when the heart
> itself is destroyed and the Huntsman is no more, the
> animating Title’s fire flits back to the Keeper whence it
> came (p. 263)

It seems clear that the designers intended for the Huntsman's existence to last longer than a dream, but the rules don't seem to support that.

Does the True Fae move the heart to a different Bastion every night? That would seem very... *tedious* to do for one of the Gentry. It doesn't really make sense to me.

So, how can a Huntsman exist for longer than a single dream?

Answer (score 3):

As our group interpret it; **Yes, the Huntsman remains in existance**

As the Bastions crumble into nothingness, the heart needs to be extracted and placed into the next.

> Does the True Fae move the heart to a different Bastion every night?

I don't see this as the biggest hindrance. The Huntsmen are a great tool for the True Fae, and what may seem like tedious logistics to us is simply a rhythm for them. Like arming beartraps, but in the dreamscape.

From our stance, it comes down to meta-economics. It is easier to store and move a heart than to create new valid Huntsmen. The Bastions are created with a seemingly infinite resource, the Huntsmen are not.

And in the end, it comes down to opportunities for great stories. Does the huntsman get a glimpse of the location of his heart, as everything evaporates around them? Does the fae have to time things correctly? Can the collapse of the Bastion somehow be falsely triggered in order to unlock the heart? Can a single Huntsman be recycled, as his hatred for specific changelings grows?

The rules-as-written tug both ways, so this is simply what our group decided for ourselves.